# JavaFX MediaPlayer does not play unc network files

Tags: media-player, media, javafx-8, unc

I want to play movie files using the MediaPlayer of JavaFX (Java Version 1.8.0_05) under Windows 7. 
I used the FileChooser class, so in my application local files and UNC network files can be selected during runtime.

Excerpt from my code:

```
String textPath = ...
Path fileOnDisk = Paths.get(textPath);
...
Media media= new Media(fileOnDisk.toUri().toString());
...
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(media);
```

If a **local file** has been selected then everythings works **fine**. As an example the Media object contains then the following URL (read out in the debugger):

```
media.url = "file:/D:/_Medien/Photo/Familie/2014_06_26%20Sensapolis%20Geburtstag%2010%20Adrian/56%20Holzgerüst%20klettern_AxelLeanderSteffen.MP4";
```

...and the mediaPlayer can be built without any problems.

I have copied this file to my NAS drive. Now if the same file has been selected **from the NAS** (using UNC syntax) then the Media object could also be built and contains the following url attribute:

```
media.url = "file://VERBATIMNAS/public/Photo/Familie/2014_06_26%20Sensapolis%20Geburtstag%2010%20Adrian/56%20Holzgerüst%20klettern_AxelLeanderSteffen.MP4";
```

But as soon as the MediaPlayer is built with the Media pointing to a UNC then I get the following **exception**:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" MediaException: UNKNOWN : com.sun.media.jfxmedia.MediaException: Could not create player! : com.sun.media.jfxmedia.MediaException: Could not create player!
    at javafx.scene.media.MediaException.exceptionToMediaException(MediaException.java:146)
    at javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer.init(MediaPlayer.java:511)
    at javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer.<init>(MediaPlayer.java:414)
    at de.kissphoto.view.mediaViewers.MovieViewer.setMedia(MovieViewer.java:216)
```

***What do I do wrong to play media with UNC paths.. or is this a bug in JavaFX?***

Note: both file paths were not entered manually but by using JavaFX's FileChooser in my application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do this

```
media = new Media(file.toURI().toURL().toExternalForm());
System.out.println("media "+media.getSource());
```

and get this (same file going through file tree and network, my Downloads folder is shared by name on the computer named Amd (no imagination here:) )

> media file:/D:/Downloads/oow2010-2.flv
>
> media file:////Amd/Downloads/oow2010-2.flv

and it works.  I don't understand why you have .jpg files.  Can you open them with media player?  I can't.

Comment: Hello Brian, no "jpg" was a copy/paste failure from the debugger window. Sorry for confusion. I use mp4 files. Adding "toURL().toExternalForm()) has no effect. But your idea made me curious, but I do not understand it. Therefore I added the following code:

Comment: System.out.println("URI=" + fileOnDisk.toUri());
        System.out.println("URL=" + fileOnDisk.toUri().toURL());
        System.out.println("Ext=" + fileOnDisk.toUri().toURL().toExternalForm());

Comment: I receive the following output

Comment: URI=file://verbatimnas/public/Photo/Familie/2014_06_26%20Sensapolis%20Geburtstag%2010%20Adrian/31%20Kart%20fahren_Adrian_David_Tamara.mp4
URL=file://verbatimnas/public/Photo/Familie/2014_06_26%20Sensapolis%20Geburtstag%2010%20Adrian/31%20Kart%20fahren_Adrian_David_Tamara.mp4
Ext=file://verbatimnas/public/Photo/Familie/2014_06_26%20Sensapolis%20Geburtstag%2010%20Adrian/31%20Kart%20fahren_Adrian_David_Tamara.mp4

Comment: So for me there is absolutely no difference visible. Can you please explain? Do you think this is a bug in the MP4-player (you used flv which is an older/original implementation in JavaFX...)? In the end I receive the same exception when building the player...:-(

Comment: The only difference I see is you use path and I used file.  I'm pretty sure whatever you do, you need the 4 //// .  It's not a problem with mp4/flv but with the UNC to URL naming.  Just try a replace("file://","file:////") in your name and see if it works.

Comment: It works :-) The problem is the Path.toUri() method which does only produce "file://". If I use content = new Media(fileOnDisk.toFile().toURI().toString()); then it works and "file:////" is produced. So it is a bug in nio not in JavaFX ;-) Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I know I might get dinged for this answer, but...

I believe this is a bug in NIO.  Thus, the best thing anyone can do is work around the bug.  Some workarounds are more elegant than others.  Here's one that absolutely works, but it's fairly crude:

`new MediaPlayer(new Media(path.toUri().toString().replaceFirst("file://", "file:////")));`